# How can I load multiple textures/materials to a model using Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, textures

I'm using some sample code and I just added my model using the JSONLoader. I can load objects with just one texture and they paint just right. But after I import an object, in this case a house with different textures/materials (grass, roof, windows, etc), but my model just appears in plain gray.

This is my example up and running:
http://trakalas.com/test/sandbox.php

This is the model (.3ds) in Blender before exporting it as .js:
[Image of model in Blender with textures](http://trakalas.com/test/images/model.png)

And here's the main code I'm using:

```
<script>

// MAIN

// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
// custom global variables
var cube;

init();
animate();

// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{
    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,550,50);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  

    // RENDERER
    if ( Detector.webgl )
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    else
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // EVENTS
    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });

    // CONTROLS
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    // STATS

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

    // LIGHT
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,250,50);
    scene.add(light);

    // FLOOR
    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/checkerboard.jpg' );
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.position.y = -0.5;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(floor);

    // SKYBOX/FOG
    var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
    var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff, side: THREE.BackSide } );
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
    // scene.add(skyBox);
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x9999ff, 0.00025 );

    //////////////
    // THE REST //
    //////////////

    addSomething(-120,100,1);
}

function addSomething(posx,posy,posz) {
    var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    jsonLoader.load("models/residential_001.js",
            function (geometry) {
                addObject(geometry,posx,posy,posz)
            });
}

function addObject(geometry,posx,posy,posz) {

    var materialArray = [];
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Asphalt .bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Brick Ru.bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Brick Wh.bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Grass Gr.bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Lead.bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Poured c.bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Roof 4.bmp' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Wood Gra.bmp' ) }));
    var houseMaterials = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(materialArray);                  

    house = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, houseMaterials);
    house.position.set(posx, posy, posz);
    house.scale.set(100, 100, 100);
    scene.add(house);
}


function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
    update();
}

function update()
{
    if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
    { 
        // do something
    }

    controls.update();
    stats.update();
}

function render() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

</script>
```

What's the right way to load mats/textures to an object like mine?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing only the geometry from the JSON model file, why not importing both geometry and materials?

```
            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "models/residential_001.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
                house = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
                house.position.set( -120, 100, 1 );
                house.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                scene.add( house );
            } );
```

Comment: Ok. I'll try this in a few minutes to check the results. So there would be no way to change the materials in the "run time"?

Comment: Great. I guess I still need to learn a lot from Three.js and JSON. I thought that was not possible to load both things at the same time. Thanks!